# Way to "find & replace" on android device in multible files

Tags: applications

Is there a way, possible an app free (without obligations demanted) avaliable, or tricks, to find and replace strings in many files, such as html?

(Note: a IT-dummy is asking)

Answer (score 0):

Download [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux), install `sed` by running

```
packages install sed
```

and you'll be able to batch replace them with Regular Expressions. <s>Now you have [two problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20842/350567)!</s>